# Backbone.js with Rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, backbone.js, routes

I have backbone view that navigates url to `localhost:3000/about` but when i do realod page, Rails routing takes care of routing and redirects me to rails page, not Backbone view. I was reading some tutorials about backbone routing, for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/803073/BackBone-Tutorial-Part-Understanding-Backbone-js-R but anything i do, it doesn't work. Is it even possible to route page after reload to correct backbone view, as it is easy for Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal. When the route is hit, your backend router will fetch and return the corresponding rails view if the router is configured to do so.
When the page is loaded into the browser, only at this moment the backbone router should be instantiated.
By default, Backbone uses hashtags# to route, but by instantiating the router with `pushstate:true`, you can fetch templates from the backend without losing front end state in your application.